# How to unpress a jButton?

Tags: jbutton

I have a jButton that calls a function.  This function can take up to a minute to complete. During this time the jButton stays pressed.  Is there a way to unpress the jButton?

I have tried

```
jButton.setEnabled(true);
jButton.setEnabled(false);
```

but these do not seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do the minute of processing in the GUI thread. Use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) instead.