# "Unpress" JButton which is looking pressed

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a `JButton` in a `Java` Application. When the button is pressed, the actions developed into its ActionListener take some seconds to finish, and the button looks like pressed all that time.

I want to remove this look, since it looks like the application had frozen.

I have seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517963/how-to-unpress-a-jbutton), but I would prefer a different solution to avoid changing a lot of code.

Is this easily possible to achieve?

Comment: It doesn't "look" like the application has frozen. It **has** frozen. Long treatments should not be done in the event dispatch thread. Use a SwingWorker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource sensitive tasks MUST not be performed in UI Thread (the thread which handles UI clicks and other activities visible to user), You need to separate the time consuming tasks to some other thread.

Another option will be to show a progress bar or something like that till the action is over.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start a new Thread? That might be a nice idea if you just want it to do that.. Change the text to "Loading" or something, and then make the thread do the work.